# Is it possible to run crontab when a button on my custom website is triggered

Tags: shell-script, cron

I want to make many tasks(different shell script) run with crontab by clicking on a button on website to start all tasks specified in crontab. Is it possible to do this? Please provide me the recommendation.

Comment: You can run shell scripts by triggering them via web server. However, this has nothing to do with `crontab` which is a technique for running scripts triggered by time only.

Comment: you could have `crontab` run a script that checks if the button was clicked

Comment: @Ned64 can you then tell us please how to run such a shell script via the web browser please.

Comment: @MoisésBriseñoEstrello I would suggest somethink like the answer by Yevhen Stasiv below. One could either have `php` execute something server-side, or have it 
"drop" a flag file which would then be detected by a local script (more flexibility and security, avoiding `exec`).

Answer (score 2):

As you are looking for an 'on demand' click of the button script execution, you do not need to use crontab.

You can simply use something like PHP's [shell_exec()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) or [exec()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) to achieve your goal.

If you wish to execute previously set up crons on demand, something like `run-parts /etc/cron.daily` can be passed to the above functions.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, the exec() function worked perfectly, thank you!